# Can we prove this statement?

Tags: calculus

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}.$ Is it true that

$$
a,c,a+\frac{b-c}{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow a-\frac{b+c}{2}\notin \mathbb{Z}\ ?
$$

How to prove that?

Comment: This is true if we restrict $b \in \Bbb{Z}$. Do you want me to prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false. Pick $a = 0.5; c = 0.5, b = -1.5$.

Answer (score 0):

[@JohnHughes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/114036/john-hughes) is completely correct when he says this statement is false, but when we restrict it to $b \in \Bbb{Z}$, it becomes true.

We have $a+\frac{b-c}{2} \notin \Bbb{Z}$. Now, when we subtract a non-integer by an integer, it yields a non-integer, so if we subtract this by $b$, we will get another non-integer. This means the following is not an integer:
$$a+\frac{b-c}{2}-b=a+\frac{b-c}{2}-\frac{2b}{b}=a+\frac{-b-c}{2}=a-\frac{b+c}{2}$$
Thus, $a-\frac{b+c}{2} \notin \Bbb{Z}$, so we are done.

Comment: there is no restriction on $b$. Thanks.